# Htaccess Rewrite Rule - direct from mysite.com to www.mysite.com

Tags: .htaccess

can anyone tell me how to redirect page from mysite.com to www.mysite.com?
Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If `mod_rewrite` is available, you could add this code to mysite.com's .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =mysite.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your mysite.com_folder/.htaccess :

```
RedirectPermanent / http://www.mysite.com/
```

Regards